# how to make NA object of arbitratry class

Tags: r

I am trying to make a function that should return `NA` of the same class as function's input. So, for example, `myNA('abc')` returns `NA_character_`, `myNA(123L)` - `NA_integer_`, etc.
I tried something like this:

```
myNA <- function(inp){
  as(NA, class(inp))
}
```

but it doesn't cover all scenarios: if I call `myNA(as.Date('2000-01-01'))`, I get an error:

```
Error in as(NA, class(inp)) : 
  no method or default for coercing “logical” to “Date”
```

UPD. testing solutions from @Anoushiravan R and @Ronak Shah:

```
myNA_as <- function(inp){
  as(NA, class(inp))
}

myNA_struct <- function(inp){
  structure(NA, class = class(inp))
}

myNA_class <- function(inp){
  `class<-`(NA, class(inp))
}

identical(myNA_as(123L),     NA_integer_) # TRUE
identical(myNA_struct(123L), NA_integer_) # FALSE
identical(myNA_class(123L),  NA_integer_) # TRUE

identical(myNA_as('abc'),     NA_character_) # TRUE
identical(myNA_struct('abc'), NA_character_) # FALSE
identical(myNA_class('abc'),  NA_character_) # TRUE

myDate <- as.Date('2000-01-01')
identical(myNA_as(myDate),     as.Date(NA)) # ERROR
identical(myNA_struct(myDate), as.Date(NA)) # FALSE
identical(myNA_class(myDate),  as.Date(NA)) # FALSE

dput(myNA_struct(myDate)) # structure(NA, class = "Date")
dput(myNA_class(myDate))  # structure(NA, class = "Date")
dput(as.Date(NA))         # structure(NA_real_, class = "Date")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `class` -

```
myNA <- function(inp){
  `class<-`(NA, class(inp))
}

class(myNA('abc'))
#[1] "character"

class(myNA(123L))
#[1] "integer"

class(myNA(Sys.Date()))
#[1] "Date"
```

---

Another option is to invoke `as.` class name function of the input type.

```
myNA_2 <- function(inp) {
  match.fun(paste0('as.', class(inp)))(NA)  
}

myDate <- as.Date('2000-01-01')
identical(myNA_2(123L),  NA_integer_) 
#[1] TRUE
identical(myNA_2('abc'),  NA_character_)
#[1] TRUE
identical(myNA_2(myDate),  as.Date(NA)) 
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah! Interestingly, result for date is not identical to `as.Date(NA)` because the latter stores `NA_real_` (see update in my question) - but for me this solution still works.

Comment: I added another option which I think satisfies the tests that you included.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `structure` function to create an object of a given class:

```
myNA <- function(inp){
  structure(NA, class = class(inp))
}

y <- myNA(as.Date('2000-01-01'))
class(y)
[1] "Date"
```

Comment: Thanks Anoushiravan! For my purposes, Ronak's solution is a bit better in case of primitive types like `NA_integer_`, `NA_character_`, etc. (see update in my question) - but yours is actually useful too!

Comment: Great option with `structure`

Comment: Thank your dear @akrun, I learned it while I was studying S3 on OOP. But apparently there is a problem with it and in some case as the OP mentioned it doesn't lead to the desired output. For example `identical(myNA(123L), NA_integer_) # FALSE` whereas it should've been TRUE.